# How to find the list and order of classes the JVM is trying to load (rather than the ones already loaded)

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to debug an issue where Sun JVM is trying to load a class which is not used by the static method I call, and it is resulting in a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Details below:

Method `A.x()` calls `B.getTZ_OFFSET()` and it runs into `NoClassDefFoundError` for `OraclePreparedStatement` even before the control reaches `getTZ_OFFSET`. I had a look at the all the static variables and blocks in `B` and none of them refer to `OraclePreparedStatement` or anything even closely related to that. I'm assuming that just importing the class doesn't cause the class to be loaded.

How do I find out the dependency, based on which JVM is trying to load `OraclePreparedStatement`?

The switch `-verbose:class` only gives the list of classes that have successfully been loaded, not the ones the JVM is trying to load. Is there a way to get that info as well?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I'm aware that importing ojdbc.jar causes the problem to vanish, but I'm more interested in the root cause, as to why it's trying to load it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The class your JVM cannot find may be referenced in a number of places: in the argument list of the method you call, return type, class (static) members of the class you are using, class members of any super classes and static initializers. You have to check all these places to find the hidden reference. The NoClassDefFoundError may also be masking some other error you get, for example an exception object that gets created and references the non existent class.

One way to determine the order classes are loaded is to implement your own class loader. You only need to extend class ClassLoader and override method loadClass(String, boolean), whereby you could print to standard out the name of the class being requested and then delegate to super.loadClass(String, boolean).